# How many nibbles?

Tags: computer-architecture

The question reads:
You know a byte is 8 bits. We call a 4 bit-quantity a nibble.If a byte-addressable memory has a 14-bit address, how many nibbles of storage are in this memory?

My answer:
Now I simply did the math and put down 3.5 nibbles; however, this is wrong according to the book which states 32768 nibbles. I am confused here can anyone please explain how this is so?

Comment: What does the address do? Where does it point too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you have some misconception about the adresses. 14-bit address means that you can address \$2^{14}=16384\$ memory locations. While each memory location contains a byte, which is two nibbles. So the total number of nibbles would be \$16384\cdot 2=32768 \$